# C# Formのフォント(Font)を動的に変更する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: c#, winforms

FormのFontはVisual Studioのデザイナー上で変更できることは確認していますが、
コード上で設定する変更する方法を教えて下さい。

例えば、設定ファイルに設定したフォントでForm部品のフォントを統一したいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コントロールに対して

```
form1.Font = new Font("フォント名", 12);
```

のように設定します。

なお`Control.Font`はアンビエントプロパティですので、明示しない限り親コントロールの設定が反映されます。ですので通常はフォームのみ指定すればよいです。